# Visual Studio 2022 Git "Manage Branches" not working

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022

When I enter git Manage Branches in VS2022, I don't see any option to merge branch to Master (or rebase). All the options on right-click seems to be disabled.(check screenshot)

Top Menu "Git" -> "Manage Branches"

n.b. I am able to commit and push.

Any reasons?

[image: No option to merge or rebase]

Comment: What do you mean "enter manage branches"? Where do you enter it? Is the popup in the screenshot from right clicking? If so what did you right click on?

Comment: Top Menu "Git" -> "Manage Branches", yes when I right-click on the "TestBranch", all options are disabled

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That part is more clear now. I have a few more questions for clarification: What did you right click on to get that menu? What branch is currently checked out? I assume `master` since it is bold. Is that right? What branches do you want to merge? (Apologies if I repeated some questions you just answered. I posted this before I saw your new comment.)

Comment: In your screenshot, it doesn't seem like you have the target branch selected. Are you selecting that? You should not be clicking on the repository but the branch you want to merge. [click branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJzSs.png) vs [click repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjCmw.png)

Comment: I see exactly what @JeffMercado sees. The only way to get that screenshot is to right click on the repo (BulkyBook) instead of the branch. If that isn't the problem, please provide a screenshot showing the disabled options.

Answer (score 0):

I need to post that this problem has been solved after I re-opened Visual studio, and no it wasn't that I didn't have the target branch selected. I would call this a hiccup since it didn't happen again. Thanks for the help